# joining a list with newline characters to pass as CL argument

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to join a list in python that contains several strings, some of which have \t and \n characters in them to create a string.

Say my list looks like this:

```
ll = ['list', 'of', '\tstrings', '\n\twith', 'newline', '\tcharacters']
ss = ':::'.join(ll)
print ss
```

prints ss with their \n and \t characters formatted:

```
list:::of:::    strings:::

     with:::newline:::  characters\
```

While what I want it to print is:

```
'list:::of:::\tstrings:::\n\twith:::newline:::\tcharacters'
```

---

I've tried:

```
ss =[]
for l in ll:
    ss.append(repr(l))
ss = ':::'.join(ll)
```

which does the same thing as above

and:

```
ss = ''
for l in ll:
    ss += (repr(l)) + ':::'

print ss.strip(':::')
```

which is close but prints:

```
'list':::'of':::'\tstrings':::'\n\twith':::'newline':::'\tcharacters'
```

Tried a few more hacks but none seem to get me what I need.

The reason I need it like above is because  I am writing CL arguments to a script that I call later on another machine. Passing a list as a CL argument doesn't work, so I was going to pass the list as a string (joined by ':::') and then on the other slide, split back into a list using ':::'. This works when just using join and split on the original list, however throws an error when I call the python script using the hardcoded CL arguments, because there's are newlines in list turned string argument.  The last example works when passed through to the second machine, however gives me this list when I split it back:

```
["'list'", "'of'", "'\\tstrings'", "'\\n\\twith'", "'newline'", "'\\tcharacters'"]
```

when instead I need:

```
['list', 'of', '\tstrings', '\n\twith', 'newline', '\tcharacters']
```

**UPDATE**: I tried all of the suggestions below and more and still couldn't figure it out, so for now I'm just dumping the list into a text file on the first server, passing the file name instead of the list, then reading the text file to a list on the second server. Hopefully this workaround will work but i'm still looking for suggestions for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The *joined* string is already as you want it. You can confirm this by printing its representation:

```
ll = ['list', 'of', '\tstrings', '\n\twith', 'newline', '\tcharacters']
ss = ':::'.join(ll)
print repr(ss)
# 'list:::of:::\tstrings:::\n\twith:::newline:::\tcharacters'
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps, however, if I pass repr(ss) as the argument, and then try to split it on the other side:

Comment: You don't need to pass `repr(ss)`, pass `ss` itself

Comment: I tried but can't pass ss because the argument getting written to the shell script that calls python on the other side is separated by newlines, which throws an error when calling the script with this arg

Comment: It does work to pass repr(ss), however the result on the otherside when I split it back into a list is this: ["'list", 'of', '\\tstrings', '\\n\\twith', 'newline', "\\tcharacters'"]

Answer (score 1):

Given the `ss` in your first code:

```
print ss.encode("string_escape")
```

(or possibly "unicode_escape" if there's any possibly of non-ASCII characters)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually want the tabs and newlines for anything other than passing as arguments to some other system, you should probably use raw strings (`r"\n\twith"`) to keep all the codes from ever being interpreted as escape codes.

No need to do data conversions that serve no purpose that you're just going to undo.